# Why my database-ajax call and the buttons are not working?

Tags: ajax

guys, I try to create a simple full stack application including the database. The users can delete the form row easily. However, I checked my ajax and view file, there is nothing wrong why I got

```
jquery.min.js:2 DELETE http://localhost:3000/delete/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)
send @ jquery.min.js:2
ajax @ jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ main.js:6
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:2
v.handle @ jquery.min.js:2
main.js:14 {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}
jquery.min.js:2 XHR failed loading: DELETE "http://localhost:3000/delete/[object%20Object]".
```

AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Delete-button").on('click',function(){
        var id = $(this).data(id);
        var url = '/delete/' + id;
        if(confirm('Delete Recipe?')){
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                method: "DELETE",
                success: (result)=>{
                    console.log("Sucess! Deleting the item!");
                    window.location.href = '/';
                },
                error:(err)=>{
                    console.log(err);
                }
            })
        }
    })
});
```

index.html file

```
 <button id = "Delete-button" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data_id = "{id}">Delete</button>
```

Comment: For the database part:
`app.delete('/delete/:id',(req,res)=>{
    pg.connect(cs,function(err, client, done){
        if (err){
            return console.error("error fetching from the pool", err);
        }
       client.query('DELETE FROM recipes WHERE id = $1;',
       [req.params.id]);
        done();
        res.send(200);
      })
});`

Answer (score 1):

`jquery.min.js:2 DELETE http://localhost:3000/delete/[object%20Object]` is the issue.

The problem is : `var id = $(this).data(id);` which give you an object.

I suggest you to use `var id = $(this).attr("data_id");` instead.

You should see this tho : https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in Delete

how is the id value populated
Also the below statement, doesn't return a plain string but rather an object.
var id = $(this).data(id);

in the below statement
jquery.min.js:2 DELETE http://localhost:3000/delete/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)
[object%20Object] <- This is what is the issue

Comment: Okay.. So could you give me some guidance in fixing it? I am a kind of new to the backend...